# How can I set an input range as multiple worksheet ranges?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to combine three sheets for an object

```
Set InputRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("COO Line Count", "SU Line Count", "MR Line Count")).Range("A2:A100")
```

It is not working.  Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VBA Range object does not support multi-sheet (3-D) ranges: you would need separate Range objects for each sheet